# VB.NET Console.foregroundcolor as boolean?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

i am making a console application and I want to make the Console.foregroundcolor code into a boolean, so that if the value is true, the text color will be green, and if it is false it will be red.
Thank you!

Comment: `Console.foregroundcolor code into a boolean` you cannot do that... What you may want to do is to have a boolean flag to determine the `Console.Foregroundcolor`

Comment: What you are looking for is the `if` statement. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simply making a variable and an if statement will help you out here, I'll do an example as you haven't specified what its for:

```
Dim False As String = console.foregroundcolor = consolecolor.Red
Dim True As String = console.foregroundcolor = consolecolor.Green
```

Then do your coding around and when it comes to the moment whether it needs to be verified just either make:

Verification = False

**OR**

Verification = True

Then do the following 'If' statement:

```
If Verification = True
True                                       (To change the text colour)
Console.Writeline("This is True!")
ElseIf Verification = False
False                                      (To change the text colour)
Console.Writeline("This is False!")
EndIf
```

This will either display green text with "This is True!" written, or red text with "This is False!" written.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using an extension method.

```
Module ExtensionMethods

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function ToColor(ByRef b As Boolean) As System.ConsoleColor
        If b Then
            Return ConsoleColor.Green
        Else
            Return ConsoleColor.Red
        End If
    End Function

End Module
```

Then you can just call `.ToColor()` on your boolean

```
Dim myBool As Boolean = True

Console.ForegroundColor = myBool.ToColor
Console.WriteLine("This is green")

myBool = False
Console.ForegroundColor = myBool.ToColor
Console.WriteLine("This is Red")

Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
```

[image: Color foreground console app]